# Lightbox effect (with minimum javascript) issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, lightbox

I want to create a lightbox with javascript at minimum level (and no external .js file). I'm very new to JS so I don't know how to solve some problems properly.

I have a set of links in a gallery-style format. Like this one:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';document.getElementById('popUpContainer').style.display='block';document.getElementById('post03').style.display='block'" class="box col3" id="pan03"></a>
```

It loads a "panel" in lightbox style. Like these ones:

```
 <div id="popUpContainer">
  <div id="popUp">
    <div class="bigPan" id="post01"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post02"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post03"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post04"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post05"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post06"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post07"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post08"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post09"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post10"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post11"></div>
    <div class="bigPan" id="post12"></div>          
  </div>
 </div>
```

The css is this:

```
#overlay {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #FFD365;
            z-index: 300;
            opacity: 0.7;

    }

    #close {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 301;
            background-color: black;
    }

    #popUpContainer {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            left: 50%;
            top: 135px;
            padding: 0px;
    }

    #popUp {
            width: 800px;
            height: 520px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;
            z-index: 400;
    }

    .bigPan {
            margin:0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #post01 {background-color: #F47A44; display: none;}
    #post02 {background-color: #558F26; display: none;}
    #post03 {background-color: #E30613; display: none;}
    #post04 {background-color: #0E84B4; display: none;}
    #post05 {background-color: #4E2583; display: none;}
    #post06 {background-color: #95C11F; display: none;}
    #post07 {background-color: #009FE3; display: none;}
    #post08 {background-color: #D7007F; display: none;}
    #post09 {background-color: #E6332A; display: none;}
    #post10 {background-color: #E29924; display: none;}
    #post11 {background-color: #008D36; display: none;}
    #post12 {background-color: #EB5B93; display: none;}
```

Ok. Everything is working fine, except when I click another link to show another panel, it loads the last panel loaded before. This is the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

So I'd like to fix this problem and, if possible, I would like you to help me clean the code with the use of the `<script>` tag and arrays, I think.

Thank you in advance.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqhRG/)

Comment: The best thing you could do is creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopup(anchor) {
        console.clear();
        var target = anchor.getAttribute("href").replace("#", "");
        console.log("Anchor clicked to show div with id: " + target);

        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("popUpContainer").style.display = "block";

        var popup = document.getElementById("popUp");
        var posts = popup.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var post = posts[i];
            if (post.id == target) {
                console.log("div with id: " + post.id + " is being shown");
                post.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                console.log("div with id: " + post.id + " is being hidden");
                post.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<a id="pan03" href="#post03" onclick="showPopup(this);return false;">post03</a>
```

I'll try and get a jsFiddle up

**UPDATE**:

Here's the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3jB9p/1/

**UPDATE**:

Code for the overlay to close itself:

```
<a id="overlay" href="#" onclick="closeOverlay(this);return false;"></a>

function closeOverlay(overlay) {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popUpContainer").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("bigPan").style.display = "none";
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is a fiddle that fixes a few of my problems from previous things and cleaned up the code: http://jsfiddle.net/eqhRG/2/

Comment: I've created a  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqhRG/) to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: @UendelQuintela I understand the problem. That's why I posted a solution that uses a function that doesn't have as much hardcoded Javascript in the HTML - it just uses a function call. So my point was that you need to change the `<a>` to look like mine and then use the function I provided. Of course, you might need some tweaking.

Comment: Your solution is the closest approach of what I would like to do, but for some reason it didn't work. Could you please apply this to the jsFiddle I've created so I can figure out if the problem is in my CSS or HTML?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault - I forgot to include hiding the "popUpContainer" div. Here's the fiddle that seems to have it working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eqhRG/2/

Comment: @UendelQuintela Sorry, I meant "I forgot to include showing the div". The fiddle seems to work though

Comment: Thank you. It should be working, but the console says that it can't find the variable "showPopUp". Like this:

"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showPopup"

I've tried change the quotes from the tag attribute onclick, but it didn't work. Could you possibly know what's going on in the code?

Comment: @UendelQuintela Do you mean when you try to use it in your code? Make sure the capitalization is correct - either stick with `showPopup` or `showPopUp` and use it everywhere - go through and make sure it is correct.

Comment: I've noticed that even in the jsFiddle you made the popUp div isn't showing at all. I copied everything the way you coded but it has the same behavior (not showing the panels).

Comment: Nevermind, I think the problem was that the object console has no method "clear". So I erased that line and everything is working fine now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize when you are new to JS is that external javascript files are your friends. Using external files allows you to write modular, reusable code that's easy to work with and expand. So, the first thing I would ask is why can't you use external files?

The problem your having seems to be caused by the fact that you aren't hiding the previously opened panel.

You *could* change it to this: `<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';document.getElementById('popUpContainer').style.display='block';document.getElementById('post03').style.display='block';;document.getElementById('post02').style.display='none'" class="box col3" id="pan03"></a>`

But that wouldn't be a very good solution if you wanted to move panels around or have lots of panels. You could store all the popups in an array and use that array to show and hide the one you want. Or, you could do what a lot of lightbox plugins do, which is put your popup divs somewhere, hidden, and when you want to see a panel replace the panel's HTML with the popups HTML and simply show the panel and overlay. Using `innerHTML` you can do this very easily.

Comment: I'm coding a hotsite and the guy who uploads the content don't want me to upload any files except the html one and the images. (I really don't know why).

Comment: Very strange. I've worked with clients like this and they are never worth the stress.